# Procreation of Weeping Angels

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

How do Weeping Angels reproduce? Are the cherubs supposed to be juvenile Weeping Angels?

Comment: I'd be amazed if there's any information at all about this. I'd honestly expect the answer to just be "we don't know".

Comment: Not sure if this is fanfiction or canon but - yes [cherubs are baby angels](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Weeping_Angel)

Comment: Do they have to reproduce? Why do you assume they do?

Comment: With the lights off.

Comment: @Fivesideddice, given that the eleventh Doctor has already declared them the deadliest, most powerful, most malevolent lifeform **evolution** has ever produced, I'd presume that they have been subject to evolution via natural selection like other lifeforms. That would necessarily entail procreation. Moreover, it's not like they are absolutely immortal no matter what, they have to sustain themselves and they can indeed die of starvation. Wouldn't procreation, then, be the most successful strategy to ensure the continued existence of their species? Or at least that is my train of thought anyway.

Comment: It's not like anyone has ever seen them in action.

Comment: When a mommy weeping angel and a daddy weeping angel love each other very much.......

Comment: Something about [the image of an angel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67746/do-all-angels-images-become-an-angel), from Flesh and Stone S5:E5, "....the image of an angel becomes itself an angel" is a pretty decent Renaissance.  More attention to this?

Comment: Through the ignorance of stone carvers making new ones.

Comment: @livresque, the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67746/do-all-angels-images-become-an-angel) and the second answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26506/why-dont-the-images-in-blink-turn-into-weeping-angels) have sufficiently explained how what you're suggesting isn't the case. Cheers.

Comment: I had thought that the weeping angels were under a curse, so these might have been the last remnants of their race.

Answer (score 2):

In "The angels take Manhattan" it's suggested, that the angels took over the other New York statues. So it seems they procreate by assimilating other statues. But how that works, is not said.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by finding a direct quote for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is not information (that I could find) about how Weeping Angels are created.
I can think of a few ideas of how they reproduce:

1. Like @Valorum said in the comment, if they reproduce like humans (aka sexual intercourse), they need to make sure there is no eye contact (turning the lights off or closing their eyes).
2. There is a possibility that there is a finite number of Weeping Angels (no one says they reproduce. The babies, for example, may not be babies but just look like that).
3. They may be a result of something we don't know about (like the big bang or some sort of sonic sculpting).